# why when using navmeshagent when clicking with the mouse the player is going to a point and keep moving there?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `FPSController` attached to it: a `RigidBody` , `Animator` , `NavMeshAgent`and two scripts: `PlayerController` and `AgentController`.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10.0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float translatioin = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
        float straffe = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
        translatioin *= Time.deltaTime;
        straffe *= Time.deltaTime;

        transform.Translate(straffe, 0, translatioin);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("escape"))
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
    }
}
```

And

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class AgentController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera camera;
    public NavMeshAgent agent;
    public bool agentControl = false;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
     if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && agentControl == true)
        {
            Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                agent.SetDestination(hit.point);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the `PlayerController` I can move around using the keys WSAD and with the `AgentController` I can click on some point on the terrain and the Agent will walk over there.

When I click for example on one of the big cubes the player is walks over it and stop near it. But then when I'm using the keys WSAD to move back away from the cube the player will keep moving automaticaly back to the cube.

Like a magnet that make the player keep moving to the cube to the same point I clicked on before.

On the `FPSCamera` I have a script: Just to use the mouse look around.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class camMouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector2 mouseLook;
    Vector2 smoothV;

    public float sensitivity = 5.0f;
    public float smoothing = 2.0f;

    GameObject character;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        character = this.transform.parent.gameObject;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
         Cursor.visible = false;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;

            var md = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"));

            md = Vector2.Scale(md, new Vector2(sensitivity * smoothing, sensitivity * smoothing));
            smoothV.x = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.x, md.x, 1f / smoothing);
            smoothV.y = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.y, md.y, 1f / smoothing);
            mouseLook += smoothV;

            mouseLook.y = Mathf.Clamp(mouseLook.y, -90f, 90f);

            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-mouseLook.y, Vector3.right);
            character.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(mouseLook.x, Vector3.up);
 }
}
```

I found that while the game is running if I uncheck the `NavMeshAgent` then I will be able to walk around again fine with the keys but when the `NavMeshAgent` is on and I click on some cube it will keep moving to that cube even if I'm moving with the keys to other places.

I want to be able either using the `AgentController` and/or the `PlayerController`when the game is running.

[image: NavMeshAgent]

UPDATE:

I tried to use OnCollisionEnter and OnCollisionExit
But once I set the move to false again on the OnCollisionExit I'm getting the same problem. The reason is that I set the move to true again in the OnCollisionExit is to be able to click the mouse and move again.

So I'm stuck again.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class AgentController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera camera;
    public NavMeshAgent agent;
    public bool move = true;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
     if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && move == true)
        {
            Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                    agent.SetDestination(hit.point);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "HitPoint")
        {
            move = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        move = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably happened because you're setting the destination to positions inside the cubes, so your agent keeps trying to reach them though it's impossible.

First of all, you may want to tell your agent to stop once one of the movement keys is pressed to avoid conflicts. You can use this to stop:

```
agent.isStopped = true;
agent.velocity = Vector3.zero;
```

If this is not enought to solve the problem, one workaround would be to put a `Nav Mesh Obstacle` Component in your cubes, check `Carve` and rebake your `Nav Mesh`. This way the agent would stop in the nearest point from the one you set, outside the cube.

A second option would be to check the collision with the cubes, and tell your agent to stop once it collides with the one you clicked.

Hopefully one of these will work for you!

Comment: I updated my question with what I tried. I`m using now OnCollisionEnter and OnCollisionExit but getting the same problem when trying to reset in the OnCollisionExit so I will be able to move again. Getting the same problem when setting the move to true again.

Comment: Once you set the destination, the agent will keep trying to reach it. It's not something that you have to call on update to work. Use `agent.isStopped = true` to stop.